# How to prove $P(A \cap \sim B) = P(A) − P(A \cap B)$ using the three rules of probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, problem-solving, conditional-probability

How to prove $P(A \cap \sim B) = P(A) − P(A \cap B)$ using the three rules of probability?

I understand this logic when drawn on a Venn Diagram, but I am unsure how it translates to a formal proof.

Thanks

Comment: Might be easier to see it if you move the second term on the right over to the left side..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A\cap B^c$ and $A\cap B$ are disjoint the probability of the union is equal to the sum of probabilities, so:

$P((A\cap B^c)\cup(A\cap B))=P(A\cap B^c)+P(A\cap B)$

but the first term on the right is equal to $P(A)$, then:
$P(A)-P(A\cap B) = P(A\cap B^c)$